# opencart routes does not match any function

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

when i request this url,
https://localhost/index.php?route=product/search/ajax&keyword=brocco

opencart return an product object like

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"Broccoli (Broccoli)",
        "href":"https:\/\/localhost\/broccoli?keyword=brocco",
        "image":"https:\/\/localhost\/image\/cache\/catalog\/product\/broccoli_new-47x47.jpg"
    }
]
```

but i dont find product/search/ajax method.
`ajax` function not in

catalog/controller/product/product.php `(class ControllerProductProduct)` or catalog/controller/product/search.php `(class ControllerProductSearch)`

Comment: Did you search in `VQMOD`?

Comment: there is 2 xml files in vqmod directory but not relevant

Comment: What is opencart version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If method `product/search/ajax` is not existing on `catalog/controller/product/search.php` file then this should be in following file.

> system/modification/catalog/controller/product/search.php